# Deduce a coefficient of a cubic polynomial.

Tags: polynomials

So, I have this question which is still troubling me:

> Find the value of $k$ such that the equation $2x^3 + 3x^2 + kx - 48 = 0$ has two solutions equal in value but opposite in sign.

I've had numerous attempts at this, such as using simultaneous equations and the factor theorem, but there always seems to be a problem. I'm sure I'm missing an important step here. Any clearing up would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

So, we can assume the roots to be of the form $a,-a,b$

So using [Vieta's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html)

$a+(-a)+b=-\frac32\implies b=-\frac32$ and $a\cdot(-a)\cdot b=\frac{48}2\implies a^2=16\implies a=\pm4$

So, the roots are $\pm4,-\frac32$

Again using Vieta's formula $k=a\cdot b+(-a)\cdot b+a\cdot(-a)$

Comment: Why do you assume there's a pair of symmetric roots $\,a,-a\,$ ?

Comment: Rats, I already read the added part to the OP...annoying!

Comment: ""...if the equation has two roots equal in value but opposite in sign.""

Comment: Yup...it is annoying trying to address a question and then the OP discovers a little, tiny detailed he left out...

Comment: You forget a minus sign $a\cdot b+(-a)\cdot b+...$.

Comment: @MaMing, thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be one of the pair roots. Then $$2a^3 + 3a^2 + ka - 48 =0=2(-a)^3 + 3(-a)^2 + k(-a) - 48\Rightarrow(2a^2+k)a=0\Rightarrow k=-2a^2$$
Substitute back this to the equation one gets $$2a^3+3a^2+(-2a^2)a-48=0$$which gives $a^2=16\Rightarrow k=-2a^2=-32$.

Answer (score 1):

well you can use comparison.

$2x^3+3x^2+kx−48=(2x+a)(x+b)(x-b) = (2x+a)(x^2-b^2) = (2x^3 +ax^2 - 2b^2x - ab^2)$

so a comparison

$2x^3+3x^2+kx−48 = (2x^3 +ax^2 - 2b^2x - ab^2)$

gives us a = 3, b = 4, k=-32

so answers the question would be 
$(2x+3)(x-4)(x+4)$

sorry i am not sure of how to make superscript for power.

Comment: use $ \$ sign\ in\ the\ both\ sides\ of$ x^3  for writing $x^3$